# liferay-7 dynamic data lists hook

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-hook, dynamic-data-list

Hi I would like to create hook on Dynamic data lists in liferay 7.
Unfortunately I am not able to achieve DDLRecordServiceWrapper, according to source code it should be accessible under

```
import com.liferay.dynamic.data.lists.service.DDLRecordServiceWrapper;
```

But this class, nor service package are resolved.

In Liferay 6.x this service was available under

```
com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordServiceWrapper
```

Is it possible to create DDL hook on liferay-7 somehow?

Answer (score 0):

While using maven, this wrapper can be found inside this artifact

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.liferay.dynamic.data.lists.api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And referenced as

```
import com.liferay.dynamic.data.lists.service.DDLRecordServiceWrapper;
```

Using only liferay SDK I wasn't able to get this.